# Arbitrarily Start and Stop Process

Tags: signals, core-dump

This isn't a question about 'SIGSTP' and 'SIGSTOP'; I'm wondering if it's possible to save the state of a program in such a way that it can be stopped, saved to disk, and continued once the computer restarts, even given an environment with slightly different resources due to other processes being present (potentially through something resembling a core dump).  I already know that 'hibernate' is sort-of a way to do this, but it's a snapshot of the *entire machine* when it's saved to disk.  What if I want to transfer the snapshot of this program in-between computers?  Is it possible/feasible?  Is there already software that does this?

P.S.: If there's a better place that and admin can put this, then I'm down for it.

EDIT: I'm currently using Linux Mint, but was thinking that there might be a potentially operating system independent solution.

Comment: Check edits.  #buffer characters#

Comment: Looking into the "freezer" subsystem of Linux cgroups may start you on the right path.  No idea if it's possible to migrate such, though.

Comment: Look for "process migration" - In a way this is a subset of snapshotting the whole system (as in a VM) because in a snapshot the state of all the processes and the system is saved. There is  research (and possibly opensource software) that can do this.

Comment: you can do this with virtual machines, will be interesting in knowing if there are not very complicated alternative ways.